# PHP - Targeting every 5th and 9th element in the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I've an infinite loop which loops for WordPress posts page. I've figured out the simple loop which counts elements in the loop and replace **5th** and **9th** element with `Featured Posts`. My ideas is to target every 5th and 9th element, but now it's targeting only first 5th and 9th element.

**Here is my loop:**

```
<div class="loop">
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php 
    $i=1;
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        if ($i==5) { ?>
            <article>
            </article><!-- featured-post-ends-here -->
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', $post->post_type ); ?>
        <?php } else if ($i==9) { ?>
            <article>
            </article><!-- featured-post-ends-here -->
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', $post->post_type ); ?>  
        <?php } else {
            get_template_part( 'content', $post->post_type ); 
        }
        if ($i==9) {
            $i=0;
        }
        $i++; 
    endwhile; ?>
</div><!-- .loop -->
```

I knew I almost there, but a bit stuck on this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [modulus `%` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

```
if( (($i%9) == 0) OR (($i%5) == 0) ) {
   //Featured post
}
```

https://eval.in/203973

Comment: I knew I must use it.. So it will be `if($i%5) == 0` and `elseif ($i%9) == 0` ?

Comment: There's no need for an else. "Replace 5th and 9th element with Featured Post". You can meet both those requirements in a single `if()` using an [`or` logic operator](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: Yep I know but I didn't clearly explained what I've need, it will be different featured posts, that's why I want to separate it.

Comment: Will the featured posts depend on if either the iteration is divisible by 5 or 9?